# Mapping enum based on name in c++

Tags: c++, enums

I have an enum types

```
enum Types{
 a,
 b,
 c
}
```

Now, I am using a library that also has an enum

```
enum LibTypes{
 lib_a = 0,
 lib_b = 1,
 lib_c = 2
}
```

when I call a method defined by this library

```
int x = data->GetType(); // returns 0,1 or 2
```

I get the int values for the types. If I don't want to expose this library to the users how can I do something like this that I get the name from the enum (e.g. if '2' is returned from `GetType()` I want to get the name 'lib_c')?

I was thinking of converting the enum to a string and matching 'c' with 'lib_c'.

Comment: Have you heard of [magic_enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum)?

Comment: a namespace with named constants `const int lib_a = 0;` etc is not equivalent to your enum, but it is much closer to what enums are in C++ compared to what we would enums to be like in C++. If you want to convert the enum to string, you need some code to do that.